# Get a Rails record count without quering a 2nd time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a Rails ActiveRecord query that find all the records where the name is some token.

```
records = Market.where("lower(name) = ?", name.downcase );
rec = records.first;
count = records.count;
```

The server shows that the calls for `.first` and `.count` were BOTH hitting the database.

```
←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets" WHERE (lower(nam
e) = 'my market') LIMIT 1

←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "markets" WHERE (lower(na
me) = 'my market')←[0m
```

Why is it going to the database to get the count when it can use the results already queried?

I'm concerned about future performance. Today there are 1000 records. When that table holds 8 million rows, doing two queries one for data, and one for count, it will be expensive.

How do I get the count from the collection, not the database?

Comment: Ah. I love when I get comments on my NOOB self :)

Answer (score 10):

RactiveRecord use lazy query to fetch data from database. If you want to simple count the records, you can only call size of the retrun array.

```
records = Market.where("lower(name) = ?", name.downcase ).all
records.size
```

Comment: correct. more clarifications -> http://rhnh.net/2007/09/26/counting-activerecord-associations-count-size-or-length

Comment: Update for Rails 5. Changing records.count to records.size still resulted in an additional db query. But changing it to records.length did not, so try records.length. Also adding .all at the end did not make any difference to the query result.

Comment: t.length also results in DB query (I used Rails 5)

Comment: for rails 5, .all -> .to_a

Comment: `.size` and `.length` worked for me in Rails 5.2 however maybe the gotcha is that you need to also `includes` activerecord relations if you are counting a relation of the initial object. ie `User.first.customers.size` would require `User.includes(:customers)`

Answer (score 8):

So, `records` is an `ActiveRelation`. You would think it's an array of all your Market records that match your `where` criteria, but it's not. Each time you reference something like `first` or `count` on that relation, it performs the query retrieve what you're asking for.

To get the actual records into an array, just add `.all` to the relation to actually retrieve them. Like:

```
records = Market.where("lower(name) = ?", name.downcase).all
count = records.count
```

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 6.0.1 and Ruby 2.6.5

You will need to store the results into an array by using the `to_a`.

```
records = Market.where("lower(name) = ?", name.downcase).to_a
```

This will create the SQL query and store the results in the array `records`.

Then, when you call either `records.first` or `records.count` it will only return the data or do the calculation, not rerun a query. This is the same for `records.size` and `records.length`.

**Another Example**

I was needing to do this for a blog I am developing. I was trying to run a query to find all of the tags associated with a post, and I wanted to count how many tags there were. This was causing multiple queries until I came across the `to_a`  suffix.

So, my SQL query looks like this:

```
@tags = TagMap.where(post_id: @post).joins(:tag).select(:id, '"tags"."name"').to_a
```

This looks through my TagMap table for all records that have `post_id` equal to the `id` of the post that I am viewing. It then joins to the Tags table and pulls only the `id` of the TagMap record and the name of the tag from the Tags table. Then it puts them all into an array. I can then run `@tags.count` and it will return the number of TagMap records for that post without doing another query.

I hope that this helps anyone using Rails 6+